# Potential issues wiring a variable resistor into accelerator pedal position sensor circuit

Tags: electrical, engine-theory, modification

What are the foreseeable problems, if any, with wiring a variable resistor into the accelerator pedal position sensor circuit?

The goal is to have a variable power selector using a dial, such that as the dial is turned down, an equal change in pedal position will result in a progressively lesser change in throttle position. For example, with the dial halfway through its travel, pushing the pedal to the floor would result in a half-open throttle.

Comment: You state on the connection to the TPS, but from your description it sounds like this would only work on a drive-by-wire setup. if so, you wouldn't have a TPS, because the car would use pedal input to place the throttle in position to match. If you did apply this to a TPS vehicle, it would mean the computer would think the throttle plate would be half open and wouldn't be giving the engine the right amount of fuel (without completely reworking the fuel map, which would defeat the purpose of what you seem to want to do here.)

Comment: I don't think that's true, in all drive-by-wire systems I've seen there's a sensor in the (throttle/pedal, whichever) that feeds to the ECU, then the ECU controls the actual throttle butterfly. I'm proposing hijacking the control -> ECU wires.

Comment: Correct, but that's not a TPS. It's an accelerator pedal position sensor ... yes, semantics, but I wanted to ensure I knew what you were asking.

Comment: Oh! My mistake, I'll correct the question.

Comment: It sounds like you want to put some sort of switch in place which would limit the power of the vehicle when you don't want it to have full power? As in, some sort of "valet key" for your car?

Comment: More like a dial on the console that can be used at any time to any degree of restriction (with a lower limit of probably about 30%), to limit fuel consumption, make winter driving easier, etc.

Comment: you can buy off the shelf boxes to do this. Google "remap throttle".

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea to me, what if you need all your power?

Comment: @GdD the idea is to build a track car that's still streetable, so in most cases you won't need all the power it's capable of but have access to it when you want

Comment: @agentp I see that they make them for some cars, I'm not sure how it would work for a car with a swapped engine, but I'd imagine if they make it for a car that the engine is normally in then that would work

Comment: In that case the variable resistor you're looking for is called your foot @Ceshion

Comment: @GdD let me put it this way, I know that I have bad self-control and putting myself in a 600hp car isn't going to help-- I want to help myself out as much as possible and I'm perfectly happy to use tech to accomplish that

Comment: @GdD additionally, there's less issue of having way too much power when you don't want it/making a mistake with the throttle meaning you instantly lose traction

Answer (score 2):

The main problem that I would expect is that you'd probably get disagreements with the computers readings, which would start messing with the EFI mapping.

First problem is - does the TPS you're looking at actually use resistance on the signal to measure or does it not (although I believe the VAST majority of TPS modules do work that way). After that, is the question of, does your TPS increase or decrease resistance as it's moved to WOT?

Example would be that the signal is sending at 5vdc and returning at 3vdc at closed throttle. Then, at WOT, it returns 5vdc. In this case resistance is reduced with throttle travel therefore adding a variable resistor would result in a backward affect.

*The next issue is that (assuming resistance is increased with WOT) adding a variable resistor set to 25k Ohm, you'll have this resistance at all points of throttle position. Meaning that if the TPS supplies 45k Ohm, and you add another 25k Ohm, that the signal will fall outside the ECU's expected parameters when the throttle's closed.*

As a final note, the computers can have multiple sensors for throttle action. So if the TPS is reading something, the pedal position sensor is reading something else, this will create a conflict for the computer. That's why I say that you'd minimally get EFI issues I think.

---

I wrote all that as you guys were discussing in the comments. So to update it to match that information, it still depends on which way the sensor works, and you'll still face the problem as noted above with italics.

---

ADDED NOTE: These are what I'd call the "foreseeable" problems. There are other possible issues that you'd run into, and there are ways of building ***much*** more complex circuits to mitigate those issues as well.

Ultimately, it seems like what you're looking to handle would require some pretty advanced communication with a few different subsystems. At least with regard to fuel consumption and winter driving, that's what the various implementations of traction control and EFI are for. Allows the computer to handle data MUCH faster than a person can, and adapt accordingly.

Comment: I would think most vehicles with a drive-by-wire system will not have a TPS, but rather a motor which drives the throttle plate which the ECU manages. It doesn't really need one, because in order for the throttle motor to work correctly, it would give feedback to the ECU as a known position. Kind of opposite of how a TPS works. I'm no expert on the subject ... this is just my understanding.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  I believe that’s mostly correct (I’m also no expert in that part) but from what I was reading, some vehicles do implement (seemingly) redundant sensors. I suppose every manufacturer is looking for a patent-able way to achieve the same thing, so you’ll get oddities like that. But you’re correct, if the ECU drove a stepper motor, that would handle both functions.

Comment: Just remember that not all vehicles have a throttle plate...

Comment: @SolarMike Also true. The wider the scope of vehicles, the harder to give an accurate answer. :)

Comment: @SolarMike - Even these days, diesels have throttle plates ... go figure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 definitely no throttle plate on mine diesel duratorq 2.2litre : go figure....

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Most modern drive by wire systems have two TP (hall effect) sensors and two APP (hall effect) sensors.  Most systems APP/TPS 1 the signal goes from low to high and on APP/TPS 2 the signal goes from high to low. OR they both go low to high with a slight difference in signal voltage. The PCM compares the TPS 1/2 or APP 1/2 signals and codes/goes into limp mode if it fails a test. Even slight differences between the two signals will code.

Comment: @Ben In which case, any added resistance would mess up the PCM's calculations right? My idea is that if you added resistance to the APP, then with the pedal at the '0 position' it would get a reading for '-2 position' or something which it outside PCM parameters most likely.

Comment: Yah it would definitely code. Your best bet would be to flash a custom calibration into the PCM with any throttle changes. Most tuning communities have found ways to implement selectable maps with the push of a button.

Comment: @Ben - My point was, all the Hall effect sensors are doing are ensuring the plates are where the ECU wants them to be. With a drive-by-cable system, the TPS drives the ECU and the ECU then puts out the amount of fuel needed (along with other inputs, of course). With a drive-by-wire, the sensor (as you describe) are letting the ECU know where it's supposed to be, so the ECU is driving things (using all the other inputs, of course). While I get the DBW is "technically" a TPS, it's not performing the same function as in the DBC system.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the theory is still the same as drive by cable. you just use an electric motor instead of a cable. when talking about the tps 1/2 signals only one is used as a fuel/timing control input the other is a rationality(?) check against the other signal.

Comment: @Ben - Is it still the same? In a DBW, the ECU controls everything. I've heard note of people saying of delays in throttle reaction due to DBW, which can *mostly* be tuned out. With a DBC, the ECU is the slave of the cable and input from the TPS. It has to keep up with the incoming air being directed by the right foot with DBC, yet it controls the air seemingly at it's own whim with DBW.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it’s true it’s not exactly the same. but  the pcm still has to wait for tps to adjust. i’d  suspect that most of the delay people feel is torque limiting in the PCM. i have a light tune on my car with torque limiting functionally disabled. I’d have a hard time realistically telling the difference if i didn’t know which type it had.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 an example. https://www.dropbox.com/s/aq9t8hqdmdejqo4/ETC.png?dl=0 part throttle from a stop. Zoomed out https://www.dropbox.com/s/hv4wdidzhwpc2my/ETC2.png?dl=0